# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un arreglo me lance números pares?

Tags: c#

Quiero generar un arreglo que contenga números pares aleatorios, pero no sé cómo puedo limitarlo sólo a los pares.

Éste es mi código del arreglo:

```
int[] Numeros;
public void Vectore(int[] numeros)
{
    Numeros = numeros;
}
public void llenarVector()
{
    Random x = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<Numeros.Length;i++)
    {
        Numeros[i] = x.Next(100);
    }
}
public int[] Retorno()
{
    return Numeros;
}
```

Comment: porfavor ayuda!!!

Comment: Podrías explicar exactamente cuál es el problema? el código que pusiste llena el vector con números aleatorios de 0 a 100. Es tu objetivo llenarlo con números pares entre 0 y 100?

Comment: "Es tu objetivo llenarlo con números pares entre 0 y 100." Un poco raro pero así es, dentro del array Numeros desea almacenar únicamente números pares 0 - 100.

Comment: no me parece constructivo que alguien excepto al OP clarifique qué es lo que el OP necesita

Comment: En las respuestas veo 50, como se está preguntando por 100, pienso que el 100 debería ir en una variable y luego hacer 100 dividido 2, que es 50.

Answer (score 10):

Si necesitas que sean números pares menores que 100, podrías multiplicar por 2 simplemente

```
var random = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < Numeros.Length; i++)
{
    Numeros[i] = random.Next(50) * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta forma sería una opción:

```
    ...
    ...
    public void llenarVector(){
          Random x = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < Numeros.Length; i++)
            {               
                Numeros[i] = x.Next(50) * 2;                
            }
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco tienes un fallo. Si el número que te sale no es par, avanzas en el bucle, con lo cual esa posición del array no se rellena. Deberías poner un else en el que decremente i, así si no es par, la próxima ejecución del for guardará en la posición que le corresponde y no dejarás posiciones sin rellenar

Comment: **Corregido** @PabloSimonDiEstefano tienes razón estaba dejando posiciones en el arreglo sin agregar pares.

Comment: @Jorgesys creo que tu edición se apartó completamente de tu intención original creando así una respuesta "igual" a  la de Equiso, quizá debiste "morir" con tu respuesta aplicando cambios para mejorarla. además la descripción no coincide con el código.

Comment: @DarkFenix dejar una respuesta incorrecta no es opción.  ¿Sugieres que la borré ?

Comment: @Jorgesys no necesariamente, solo aplicar los cambios para dejar que sea incorrecta. Solo digo que son respuestas muy parecidas. tampoco voté -1 solo me causo asombro el cambio repentino. _Todos se pueden equivocar_  la acción realices depende de ti.

Answer (score 1):

También puedes desplazar un bit a la izquierda.

```
var random = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < Numeros.Length; i++)
{
    Numeros[i] = random.Next(50) << 1;
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zjb1S3

Comment: Nótese que un buen compilador generará el mismo código para desplazar a la izquierda que para multiplicar por 2. Y multiplicar por 2 en este caso resulta más claro. Pero por lo menos la respuesta es correcta.